# Can I implement django's user authentication with Neo4j?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, neo4j

I am currently in the very early stage of a new project, which uses django for the backend. I am using Neo4j (neomodel) as a graph DB for all the relations between users etc.

One thing I am struggling with at the moment is implementing the user authentication.

Is it possible to use django's user auth system together with neomodel (Neo4j)? And if yes, how would I do that?

If not, how would I implement the auth system?

This is what my user profile model looks like right now.

```
class Profile(StructuredNode):
    GENDERS = {"M": "Male", "F": "Female", "O": "Other"}
    # Properties
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    email = EmailProperty(required=True)
    password = StringProperty(required=True)
    username = StringProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)
    name = StringProperty()
    age = IntegerProperty()
    gender = StringProperty(choices=GENDERS)
    date_of_birth = DateProperty()
    creation_date = DateTimeProperty(default_now=True)
```

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks :)

Comment: You'll need to write an authentication backend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn for your quick response. 
I've read through the doc and (please correct me if I'm wrong) it looks to me like my problem would be fixed by writing a custom user and user manager, right?
Because my problem is not really with the auth system but with my User model as I have to edit/customise this for it to be compatible with the django auth. As you can see, I am not very experienced with django so please correct me if I'm wrong, but that is what seems plausible to me.

Comment: It's not what you'd normally start customizing, but it is pretty easy to do. See my answer for details...

Answer (score 0):

I think django-neomodel (the admin parts) already implement that?

See

https://medium.com/neo4j/register-your-neo4j-based-models-to-the-django-admin-b58ebcd6dfc3

https://medium.com/neo4j/neo4j-for-django-developers-efd0e39e5f2e

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write an authentication backend (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).

An authentication backend is a regular class with at least the three
methods defined below

```
from myapp.profile import Profile


class Neo4jAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        """Return a profile if we can authenticate username and password.
        Otherwise, return None.
        """
        if not username or not password:
            return None

        profile = get_profile(username=username)  # you'll need to write this
        if not profile or not profile.check_password(password):
            return None

        return profile
    
    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        """Check permissions/is_active etc. here."""
        return True
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """Return a user object given the user_id.
           Used by the django authentication system to retrieve a user instance
           when a authenticated user session arrives, and to set request.user.
        """
        try:
            profile = get_profile(uid=user_id)  # you'll need to write this
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return profile if self.user_can_authenticate(profile) else None
```

you'll also need to add the following to your settings.py file (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/):

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'myapp.neobackend.Neo4jAuthBackend',   # the path to your backend
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # default django backend (for admin etc.)
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I don't really see why I would have to write a custom auth backend. Could you please explain this further?

I have made some more changes in models.py and admin.py, including adding a custom UserManager, User creation/change forms and UserAdmin class. 

Now when I run manage.py runserver I get this error: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username, name, email) specified for UserProfile.

I believe this has to do with me storing the User data as neomodel properties instead of djangos standard db fields.

Would a auth backend help with that?

Comment: If you already have a place to store user data that is not in a Django model, then it seems like a lot of work to create shadow users in django just to authenticate users -- and you'd likely need to write an authentication backend anyway to handle the peculiarities of your setup. Writing an authentication backend is pretty easy, the above code (except the parts marked) is the entire backend... (ps: IIRC then the user-profile machinery is meant for keeping extra data about a django User instance, and should therefore have a foreign key to User).